# Formulario de facturacion WordPress - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de crear un formulario que me guarde los detalles de facturación sin necesidad de realizar un pago. estoy utilizando por mientras un plugin que manda un mensaje a WhatsApp, funciona correctamente y manda los detalles del envio, pero necesito guardar antes los detalles en el Checkout y no es correcto ya que no necesitaria realizar algun pago, solo es por mediod de WhatsApp,

Este es mi codigo para el formulario, un ejemplo

```html
<form id="custom-billing-details-form" method="post">
  <label for="custom_billing_name">Nombre:</label>
  <input type="text" id="custom_billing_name"
    name="custom_billing_name" required>
  <label for="custom_billing_address">Dirección:</label>
  <input type="text" id="custom_billing_address"
    name="custom_billing_address" required>
  <button type="submit" 
    name="custom_billing_submit">Guardar en Billing Details</button>
</form>
```

Con esto estaria actualizando los datos

```
$order_id = wc_get_checkout_order_id();

update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_first_name', $custom_name);
update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_address_1', $custom_address);
```

al final el formulario no guarda los datos, quisiera saber que es lo que estoy pasando por alto o si son las variables correctas que estoy tomando de woocommerce

Comment: y que has intentado para lograr el objetivo.... te sale algun error de codigo???

Comment: para "vender por whatsapp" te conviene poner como métodos de pago habilitados "direct bank transfer" y/o "cash on delivery", el "direct bank transfer" ( o su traducción que en este momento no tengo disponible ) toma el pedido y en las instrucciones por email que recibe el cliente especifica que anote el numero de orden y lo use para la descripcion de "motivo/concepto de transferencia", una vez que recibis ( x whatsapp o email ) el comprobante de depósito, usas ese order id ( numero de orden ) para marcar la order como pagada ( manualmente desde el backend )